# How use method isEqual in react

Tags: reactjs

I use the method _.isEqual in my function:

```
const Sidebar = ({ ...props }) => {     
  function myFunction(codeMenu) {
    let menu = null;
    const listMenu = props.listMenu;

    for(var i = 0; i < listMenu.length; i++){
      if(_.isEqual(listMenu[i].code, codeMenu)){
        menu = listMenu[i];
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
...
```

But I have this error:
`'_' is not defined  no-undef`

loadsh is imported in my index.html :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using lodash via cdn, use it via npm. Please run following commands:

```
npm install lodash
```

and then import it in the file like

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

and then use it. Actually more optimal way to import is:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
```

so that extra lodash package might not be included in the bundle

Comment: `import { isEqual } from 'lodash';` would be even better to avoid submodule imports

Answer (score 1):

One reason you may getting that error is that your React bundle is executed before lodash. In that case `_` would not have been added to the global scope.

To avoid these kind of issues, I suggest ditching the CDN and instead add lodash as a dependency to your package.json file. You can then cosume lodash as a require or import.

If you import `isEqual` as `import isEqual from 'lodash/isequal'` and you're using a bundler such as Webpack, it will not bundle the other lodash functions you're not importing, dramatically reducing the amount of code your browser has to download.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `_` object is not defined. Did you import lodash like `var _ = require('lodash');` ?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to import lodash using npm install command**

Here's full code how ->

```html
 import lodash from lodash
 // Load the full build.
 var _ = require('lodash');
 // Load the core build.
 var _ = require('lodash/core');
 
 const Sidebar = ({ ...props }) => {

  function myFunction(codeMenu){
    let menu = null;
    const listMenu = props.listMenu;

    for(var i = 0; i < listMenu.length; i++){
      if(_.isEqual(listMenu[i].code, codeMenu)){
        menu = listMenu[i];
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```